# Magento 2 trigger price change using Knockout JS in "Edit / Create Configurations"

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

How we can trigger the "price change" using Knockout JS in "Edit / Create Configurations" under the product creation module ?

[image]

I can see that the values are coming from the "dynamic-rows-configurable.js" and "ConfigurablePanel.php"